# Erro no código de java

Tags: java

Estou começando a aprender programação em java, e o seguinte aconteceu:

```
ERRO!!!!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
Player cannot be resolved to a type
Player cannot be resolved to a type

at oo/oo.main.main(main.java:5)
```

```java
package oo;

public class jogador {
    public void startplayer() {
        System.out.println("Player started");
    }
}



package oo;

public class inimigo {
    public void startenemy() {
        System.out.println("Enemy started");
    }
}

package oo;

public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.startplayer();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seja bem-vindo a nossa comunidade!

O erro mencionado é que basicamente sua classe "Player" não existe, portanto não é possível criar uma instância, veja:

```
Player player = new Player();
```

Então, renomeie a classe jogador para Player e faça o teste. Lembre-se, também se essa classe estiver em um arquivo separado. O nome do arquivo deverá ser Player.java e não jogador.java

```
public class Player
```

ao invés de

```
public class jogador
```

Answer (score 3):

seu código tem alguns problemas, vou explicar sobre o erro e os demais problemas que vejo.

- no método main você está tentando instanciar um *Player*, essa classe não existe, a que você escreveu se chama *jogador*.
- as boas práticas recomendam o nome de classes *CamelCase* e começando com letra maiúscula. Também nessa ideia de nomes e para evitar problemas como esse que você está tendo, evite usar idiomas misturados no seu código.